# Dom repair and no name warning

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to fetch and process a webpage. I made a demo for you at here:

http://vaso.hu/other/dom/shop.htm

I want to parse it, and get all `child` classed, (the links and the texts) from `parent` div with Dom.

```
<?php

$Dom = new \DOMDocument();
$Dom->recover = true;
$Dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$Dom->resolveExternals = true;
$Dom->substituteEntities = true;
$Dom->validateOnParse = false;
$Dom->loadHTMLFile('http://vaso.hu/other/dom/shop.htm');
```

First, what I do not understand is this error code:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : li in http://vaso.hu/other/dom/shop.htm, line: 17

Yes, I know, there is an unwanted closing `</li>`, but this is not my html code. I search through so, and as I see, this is why `$Dom->recover` is.

The second problem is the

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://vaso.hu/other/dom/shop.htm, line: 21

Search for it, and I know, the problem is the `&` sign, I just do not know how to handle that.

So can you tell me, repair is why not repair the code, and how can I handle the `&` signs?

Anyway, here are the bad code, this is how is, deliberately not indented, and choped the head section.

```
<body>

<div class="menu"><ul></li>
<li><p><a  class="hide" href="abc" style="width:100px;" title="">xxxx</a></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"><h3><a  href="/product/cables_adapters" title="">Cabels & Adapters</a></h3></div>
<!--
more childs here
-->
</div>

</body>
```

**EDIT**
The second problem is solved by replacing the `&` signs to `&amp;` I just wondering, is this the real solution?